Searching Torah for words following an acrostic pattern
I want to search the entire written Torah [the 5 books] for possible 3 consecutive words with 3 specific letter of Hebrew alphabet based on my choice. Is there any website or program that does this?
Example: the 3 alphabet letters of Vav, vav, vav can be found in the beginning of each of these 3 consecutive words:
Veachalta Vesavata Overakhta

Maybe here: https://basehasefer.com/

It doesn't looks an hard program to write if you have the Torah as unicode text. I can do it for you if everything fails.

I made a quick & dirty Python program. Here is a test run for your consideration. It's a short free program and you only need Python.
** Edit 3 **
Here are the results for the five books of Torah.
This version replace all maqaf with space before examine the words.
You can find the program and files at https://github.com/Candid-Moe/search/tree/main
Genesis

Chapter  1
 ‫ 14 :1 ['וּלְמ֣וֹעֲדִ֔ים', 'וּלְיָמִ֖ים', 'וְשָׁנִֽים׃']
Chapter  6
 ‫ 18 :6 ['וּבָנֶ֛יךָ', 'וְאִשְׁתְּךָ֥', 'וּנְשֵֽׁי']
Chapter  7
 ‫ 7  :7 ['וּ֠בָנָיו', 'וְאִשְׁתּ֧וֹ', 'וּנְשֵֽׁי']
 ‫ 13 :7 ['וְשֵׁם', 'וְחָ֥ם', 'וָיֶ֖פֶת']
 ‫ 21 :7 ['וּבַבְּהֵמָה֙', 'וּבַ֣חַיָּ֔ה', 'וּבְכָל']
Chapter  8
 ‫ 16 :8 ['וְאִשְׁתְּךָ֛', 'וּבָנֶ֥יךָ', 'וּנְשֵֽׁי']
 ‫ 18 :8 ['וּבָנָ֛יו', 'וְאִשְׁתּ֥וֹ', 'וּנְשֵֽׁי']
 ‫ 22 :8 ['וְ֠קָצִיר', 'וְקֹ֨ר', 'וָחֹ֜ם']
 ‫ 22 :8 ['וְקַ֧יִץ', 'וָחֹ֛רֶף', 'וְי֥וֹם']
Chapter  9
 ‫ 18 :9 ['וְחָ֣ם', 'וָיָ֑פֶת', 'וְחָ֕ם']
Chapter  10
 ‫ 2  :10 ['וּמָג֔וֹג', 'וּמָדַ֖י', 'וְיָוָ֣ן']
 ‫ 2  :10 ['וְתֻבָ֑ל', 'וּמֶ֖שֶׁךְ', 'וְתִירָֽס׃']
 ‫ 6  :10 ['וּמִצְרַ֖יִם', 'וּפ֥וּט', 'וּכְנָֽעַן׃']
 ‫ 7  :10 ['וֽ͏ַחֲוִילָ֔ה', 'וְסַבְתָּ֥ה', 'וְרַעְמָ֖ה']
 ‫ 10 :10 ['וְאֶ֖רֶךְ', 'וְאַכַּ֣ד', 'וְכַלְנֵ֑ה']
 ‫ 19 :10 ['וַעֲמֹרָ֛ה', 'וְאַדְמָ֥ה', 'וּצְבֹיִ֖ם']
 ‫ 22 :10 ['וְאַשּׁ֑וּר', 'וְאַרְפַּכְשַׁ֖ד', 'וְל֥וּד']
 ‫ 23 :10 ['וְח֖וּל', 'וְגֶ֥תֶר', 'וָמַֽשׁ׃']
Chapter  12
 ‫ 16 :12 ['וּבָקָר֙', 'וַחֲמֹרִ֔ים', 'וַעֲבָדִים֙']
 ‫ 16 :12 ['וּשְׁפָחֹ֔ת', 'וַאֲתֹנֹ֖ת', 'וּגְמַלִּֽים׃']
Chapter  13
 ‫ 14 :13 ['וָנֶ֖גְבָּה', 'וָקֵ֥דְמָה', 'וָיָֽמָּה׃']
Chapter  14
 ‫ 15 :14 ['וַעֲבָדָ֖יו', 'וַיַּכֵּ֑ם', 'וֽ͏ַיִּרְדְּפֵם֙']
Chapter  19
 ‫ 12 :19 ['וּבָנֶ֣יךָ', 'וּבְנֹתֶ֔יךָ', 'וְכֹ֥ל']
Chapter  20
 ‫ 14 :20 ['וּבָקָ֗ר', 'וַעֲבָדִים֙', 'וּשְׁפָחֹ֔ת']
Chapter  21
 ‫ 14 :21 ['וַֽיְשַׁלְּחֶ֑הָ', 'וַתֵּ֣לֶךְ', 'וַתֵּ֔תַע']
Chapter  24
 ‫ 35 :24 ['וּבָקָר֙', 'וְכֶ֣סֶף', 'וְזָהָ֔ב']
 ‫ 35 :24 ['וַעֲבָדִם֙', 'וּשְׁפָחֹ֔ת', 'וּגְמַלִּ֖ים']
Chapter  25
 ‫ 4  :25 ['וָעֵ֙פֶר֙', 'וַחֲנֹ֔ךְ', 'וַאֲבִידָ֖ע']
 ‫ 13 :25 ['וְקֵדָ֥ר', 'וְאַדְבְּאֵ֖ל', 'וּמִבְשָֽׂם׃']
 ‫ 14 :25 ['וּמִשְׁמָ֥ע', 'וְדוּמָ֖ה', 'וּמַשָּֽׂא׃']
 ‫ 17 :25 ['וַיִּגְוַ֣ע', 'וַיָּ֔מָת', 'וַיֵּאָ֖סֶף']
 ‫ 34 :25 ['וַיֹּ֣אכַל', 'וַיֵּ֔שְׁתְּ', 'וַיָּ֖קָם']
Chapter  27
 ‫ 14 :27 ['וַיֵּ֙לֶךְ֙', 'וַיִּקַּ֔ח', 'וַיָּבֵ֖א']
Chapter  28
 ‫ 3  :28 ['וְיַפְרְךָ֖', 'וְיַרְבֶּ֑ךָ', 'וְהָיִ֖יתָ']
 ‫ 14 :28 ['וָקֵ֖דְמָה', 'וְצָפֹ֣נָה', 'וָנֶ֑גְבָּה']
Chapter  30
 ‫ 37 :30 ['וְל֣וּז', 'וְעֶרְמ֑וֹן', 'וַיְפַצֵּ֤ל']
 ‫ 43 :30 ['וּשְׁפָחוֹת֙', 'וַעֲבָדִ֔ים', 'וּגְמַלִּ֖ים']
Chapter  32
 ‫ 6  :32 ['וְעֶ֣בֶד', 'וְשִׁפְחָ֑ה', 'וָֽאֶשְׁלְחָה֙']
Chapter  33
 ‫ 7  :33 ['וִילָדֶ֖יהָ', 'וַיִּֽשְׁתַּחֲו֑וּ', 'וְאַחַ֗ר']
Chapter  35
 ‫ 23 :35 ['וְשִׁמְעוֹן֙', 'וְלֵוִ֣י', 'וִֽיהוּדָ֔ה']
Chapter  36
 ‫ 20 :36 ['וְשׁוֹבָ֖ל', 'וְצִבְע֥וֹן', 'וַעֲנָֽה׃']
 ‫ 21 :36 ['וְדִשׁ֥וֹן', 'וְאֵ֖צֶר', 'וְדִישָׁ֑ן']
 ‫ 26 :36 ['וְאֶשְׁבָּ֖ן', 'וְיִתְרָ֥ן', 'וּכְרָֽן׃']
Chapter  38
 ‫ 19 :38 ['וַתָּ֣קָם', 'וַתֵּ֔לֶךְ', 'וַתָּ֥סַר']
Chapter  43
 ‫ 8  :43 ['וְנָק֣וּמָה', 'וְנֵלֵ֑כָה', 'וְנִֽחְיֶה֙']
 ‫ 31 :43 ['וַיֵּצֵ֑א', 'וַיִּ֨תְאַפַּ֔ק', 'וַיֹּ֖אמֶר']
Chapter  45
 ‫ 10 :45 ['וְצֹאנְךָ֥', 'וּבְקָרְךָ֖', 'וְכָל']
Chapter  46
 ‫ 9  :46 ['וּפַלּ֖וּא', 'וְחֶצְר֥וֹן', 'וְכַרְמִֽי׃']
 ‫ 10 :46 ['וְיָמִ֛ין', 'וְאֹ֖הַד', 'וְיָכִ֣ין']
 ‫ 12 :46 ['וְאוֹנָ֛ן', 'וְשֵׁלָ֖ה', 'וָפֶ֣רֶץ']
 ‫ 13 :46 ['וּפֻוָּ֖ה\u202a[t]\u202c', 'וְי֥וֹב', 'וְשִׁמְרֽוֹן׃']
 ‫ 17 :46 ['וְיִשְׁוָ֛ה', 'וְיִשְׁוִ֥י', 'וּבְרִיעָ֖ה']
 ‫ 24 :46 ['וְגוּנִ֖י', 'וְיֵ֥צֶר', 'וְשִׁלֵּֽם׃']
 ‫ 32 :46 ['וְצֹאנָ֧ם', 'וּבְקָרָ֛ם', 'וְכָל']
Chapter  47
 ‫ 1  :47 ['וְאַחַ֜י', 'וְצֹאנָ֤ם', 'וּבְקָרָם֙']
Chapter  49
 ‫ 23 :49 ['וַֽיְמָרֲרֻ֖הוּ', 'וָרֹ֑בּוּ', 'וַֽיִּשְׂטְמֻ֖הוּ']
------------------ 

Exodus

Chapter  1
 ‫ 7  :1 ['וַֽיִּשְׁרְצ֛וּ', 'וַיִּרְבּ֥וּ', 'וַיַּֽעַצְמ֖וּ']
Chapter  2
 ‫ 16 :2 ['וַתָּבֹ֣אנָה', 'וַתִּדְלֶ֗נָה', 'וַתְּמַלֶּ֙אנָה֙']
Chapter  3
 ‫ 8  :3 ['וְהַ֣חִתִּ֔י', 'וְהָֽאֱמֹרִי֙', 'וְהַפְּרִזִּ֔י']
 ‫ 17 :3 ['וְהַ֣חִתִּ֔י', 'וְהָֽאֱמֹרִי֙', 'וְהַפְּרִזִּ֔י']
Chapter  6
 ‫ 15 :6 ['וְיָמִ֤ין', 'וְאֹ֙הַד֙', 'וְיָכִ֣ין']
 ‫ 16 :6 ['וּקְהָ֖ת', 'וּמְרָרִ֑י', 'וּשְׁנֵי֙']
 ‫ 18 :6 ['וְיִצְהָ֔ר', 'וְחֶבְר֖וֹן', 'וְעֻזִּיאֵ֑ל']
Chapter  7
 ‫ 28 :7 ['וּבְעַמֶּ֔ךָ', 'וּבְתַנּוּרֶ֖יךָ', 'וּבְמִשְׁאֲרוֹתֶֽיךָ׃']
 ‫ 29 :7 ['וּבְכָ֥ה', 'וּֽבְעַמְּךָ֖', 'וּבְכָל']
Chapter  8
 ‫ 7  :8 ['וּמִבָּ֣תֶּ֔יךָ', 'וּמֵעֲבָדֶ֖יךָ', 'וּמֵעַמֶּ֑ךָ']
 ‫ 17 :8 ['וּבַעֲבָדֶ֧יךָ', 'וּֽבְעַמְּךָ֛', 'וּבְבָתֶּ֖יךָ']
Chapter  9
 ‫ 34 :9 ['וְהַבָּרָ֛ד', 'וְהַקֹּלֹ֖ת', 'וַיֹּ֣סֶף']
Chapter  13
 ‫ 5  :13 ['וְהַחִתִּ֨י', 'וְהָאֱמֹרִ֜י', 'וְהַחִוִּ֣י']
Chapter  20
 ‫ 10 :20 ['וַאֲמָֽתְךָ֜֙', 'וּבְהֶמְתֶּ֔֗ךָ', 'וְגֵרְךָ֖֙']
 ‫ 17 :20 ['וְעַבְדּ֤וֹ', 'וַאֲמָתוֹ֙', 'וְשׁוֹר֣וֹ']
Chapter  23
 ‫ 23 :23 ['וְהַ֣חִתִּ֔י', 'וְהַפְּרִזִּי֙', 'וְהַֽכְּנַעֲנִ֔י']
Chapter  25
 ‫ 4  :25 ['וּתְכֵ֧לֶת', 'וְאַרְגָּמָ֛ן', 'וְתוֹלַ֥עַת']
 ‫ 29 :25 ['וְכַפֹּתָ֗יו', 'וּקְשׂוֹתָיו֙', 'וּמְנַקִּיֹּתָ֔יו']
Chapter  26
 ‫ 1  :26 ['וּתְכֵ֤לֶת', 'וְאַרְגָּמָן֙', 'וְתֹלַ֣עַת']
Chapter  27
 ‫ 3  :27 ['וְיָעָיו֙', 'וּמִזְרְקֹתָ֔יו', 'וּמִזְלְגֹתָ֖יו']
Chapter  28
 ‫ 4  :28 ['וְאֵפוֹד֙', 'וּמְעִ֔יל', 'וּכְתֹ֥נֶת']
Chapter  29
 ‫ 21 :29 ['וּבְגָדָ֔יו', 'וּבָנָ֛יו', 'וּבִגְדֵ֥י']
Chapter  30
 ‫ 9  :30 ['וְעֹלָ֣ה', 'וּמִנְחָ֑ה', 'וְנֵ֕סֶךְ']
Chapter  31
 ‫ 3  :31 ['וּבִתְבוּנָ֥ה', 'וּבְדַ֖עַת', 'וּבְכָל']
Chapter  34
 ‫ 7  :34 ['וָפֶ֖שַׁע', 'וְחַטָּאָ֑ה', 'וְנַקֵּה֙']
 ‫ 11 :34 ['וְהַֽכְּנַעֲנִ֔י', 'וְהַחִתִּי֙', 'וְהַפְּרִזִּ֔י']
Chapter  35
 ‫ 6  :35 ['וּתְכֵ֧לֶת', 'וְאַרְגָּמָ֛ן', 'וְתוֹלַ֥עַת']
 ‫ 22 :35 ['וָנֶ֜זֶם', 'וְטַבַּ֤עַת', 'וְכוּמָז֙']
 ‫ 23 :35 ['וְשֵׁ֣שׁ', 'וְעִזִּ֑ים', 'וְעֹרֹ֨ת']
Chapter  36
 ‫ 8  :36 ['וּתְכֵ֤לֶת', 'וְאַרְגָּמָן֙', 'וְתוֹלַ֣עַת']
 ‫ 38 :36 ['וְאֶת', 'וָ֣וֵיהֶ֔ם', 'וְצִפָּ֧ה']
Chapter  39
 ‫ 29 :39 ['וּתְכֵ֧לֶת', 'וְאַרְגָּמָ֛ן', 'וְתוֹלַ֥עַת']
------------------ 

Leviticus

Chapter  7
 ‫ 37 :7 ['וְלַֽחַטָּ֖את', 'וְלָאָשָׁ֑ם', 'וְלַ֨מִּלּוּאִ֔ים']
Chapter  9
 ‫ 19 :9 ['וְהַֽמְכַסֶּה֙', 'וְהַכְּלָיֹ֔ת', 'וְיֹתֶ֖רֶת']
Chapter  11
 ‫ 30 :11 ['וְהָאֲנָקָ֥ה', 'וְהַכֹּ֖חַ', 'וְהַלְּטָאָ֑ה']
Chapter  14
 ‫ 56 :14 ['וְלַשְׂאֵ֥ת', 'וְלַסַּפַּ֖חַת', 'וְלַבֶּהָֽרֶת׃']
Chapter  21
 ‫ 2  :21 ['וּלְאָבִ֔יו', 'וְלִבְנ֥וֹ', 'וּלְבִתּ֖וֹ']
Chapter  22
 ‫ 24 :22 ['וּמָע֤וּךְ', 'וְכָתוּת֙', 'וְנָת֣וּק']
Chapter  23
 ‫ 14 :23 ['וְלֶחֶם֩', 'וְקָלִ֨י', 'וְכַרְמֶ֜ל']
Chapter  25
 ‫ 6  :25 ['וּלְעַבְדְּךָ֣', 'וְלַאֲמָתֶ֑ךָ', 'וְלִשְׂכִֽירְךָ֙']
------------------ 

Numbers

Chapter  3
 ‫ 31 :3 ['וְהַשֻּׁלְחָן֙', 'וְהַמְּנֹרָ֣ה', 'וְהַֽמִּזְבְּחֹ֔ת']
 ‫ 36 :3 ['וּבְרִיחָ֖יו', 'וְעַמֻּדָ֣יו', 'וַאֲדָנָ֑יו']
 ‫ 37 :3 ['וְאַדְנֵיהֶ֑ם', 'וִיתֵדֹתָ֖ם', 'וּמֵֽיתְרֵיהֶֽם׃']
Chapter  4
 ‫ 31 :4 ['וּבְרִיחָ֖יו', 'וְעַמּוּדָ֥יו', 'וַאֲדָנָֽיו׃']
 ‫ 32 :4 ['וְאַדְנֵיהֶ֗ם', 'וִֽיתֵדֹתָם֙', 'וּמֵ֣יתְרֵיהֶ֔ם']
Chapter  13
 ‫ 29 :13 ['וְ֠הַֽחִתִּי', 'וְהַיְבוּסִ֤י', 'וְהָֽאֱמֹרִי֙']
Chapter  16
 ‫ 27 :16 ['וּנְשֵׁיהֶ֥ם', 'וּבְנֵיהֶ֖ם', 'וְטַפָּֽם׃']
Chapter  18
 ‫ 2  :18 ['וִֽישָׁרְת֑וּךָ', 'וְאַתָּה֙', 'וּבָנֶ֣יךָ']
Chapter  20
 ‫ 5  :20 ['וּתְאֵנָ֤ה', 'וְגֶ֙פֶן֙', 'וְרִמּ֔וֹן']
Chapter  27
 ‫ 1  :27 ['וְחָגְלָ֥ה', 'וּמִלְכָּ֖ה', 'וְתִרְצָֽה׃']
Chapter  29
 ‫ 39 :29 ['וּלְמִנְחֹ֣תֵיכֶ֔ם', 'וּלְנִסְכֵּיכֶ֖ם', 'וּלְשַׁלְמֵיכֶֽם׃']
Chapter  32
 ‫ 3  :32 ['וְדִיבֹן֙', 'וְיַעְזֵ֣ר', 'וְנִמְרָ֔ה']
 ‫ 3  :32 ['וְחֶשְׁבּ֖וֹן', 'וְאֶלְעָלֵ֑ה', 'וּשְׂבָ֥ם']
Chapter  36
 ‫ 11 :36 ['וְחָגְלָ֧ה', 'וּמִלְכָּ֛ה', 'וְנֹעָ֖ה']
------------------ 

Deuteronomy

Chapter  1
 ‫ 1  :1 ['וְלָבָ֥ן', 'וַחֲצֵרֹ֖ת', 'וְדִ֥י']
 ‫ 7  :1 ['וּבַשְּׁפֵלָ֥ה', 'וּבַנֶּ֖גֶב', 'וּבְח֣וֹף']
Chapter  3
 ‫ 17 :3 ['וְהָֽעֲרָבָ֖ה', 'וְהַיַּרְדֵּ֣ן', 'וּגְבֻ֑ל']
 ‫ 27 :3 ['וְצָפֹ֛נָה', 'וְתֵימָ֥נָה', 'וּמִזְרָ֖חָה']
Chapter  4
 ‫ 34 :4 ['וּבְמוֹפְתִ֜ים', 'וּבְמִלְחָמָ֗ה', 'וּבְיָ֤ד']
Chapter  5
 ‫ 14 :5 ['וּבִנְךָֽ', 'וּבִתֶּ֣ךָ', 'וְעַבְדְּךָֽ']
 ‫ 14 :5 ['וַ֠אֲמָתֶךָ', 'וְשׁוֹרְךָ֨', 'וַחֲמֹֽרְךָ֜']
Chapter  7
 ‫ 1  :7 ['וְהַגִּרְגָּשִׁ֨י', 'וְהָאֱמֹרִ֜י', 'וְהַכְּנַעֲנִ֣י']
 ‫ 1  :7 ['וְהַפְּרִזִּ֗י', 'וְהַֽחִוִּי֙', 'וְהַיְבוּסִ֔י']
 ‫ 13 :7 ['וַאֲהֵ֣בְךָ֔', 'וּבֵרַכְךָ֖', 'וְהִרְבֶּ֑ךָ']
 ‫ 19 :7 ['וְהָאֹתֹ֤ת', 'וְהַמֹּֽפְתִים֙', 'וְהַיָּ֤ד']
Chapter  8
 ‫ 1  :8 ['וּרְבִיתֶ֗ם', 'וּבָאתֶם֙', 'וִֽירִשְׁתֶּ֣ם']
 ‫ 3  :8 ['וַֽיְעַנְּךָ֮', 'וַיַּרְעִבֶךָ֒', 'וַיַּֽאֲכִֽלְךָ֤']
 ‫ 8  :8 ['וּשְׂעֹרָ֔ה', 'וְגֶ֥פֶן', 'וּתְאֵנָ֖ה']
 ‫ 10 :8 ['וְאָכַלְתָּ֖', 'וְשָׂבָ֑עְתָּ', 'וּבֵֽרַכְתָּ֙']
Chapter  9
 ‫ 22 :9 ['וּבְתַבְעֵרָה֙', 'וּבְמַסָּ֔ה', 'וּבְקִבְרֹ֖ת']
Chapter  11
 ‫ 1  :11 ['וְחֻקֹּתָ֧יו', 'וּמִשְׁפָּטָ֛יו', 'וּמִצְוֺתָ֖יו']
Chapter  12
 ‫ 6  :12 ['וְנִדְרֵיכֶם֙', 'וְנִדְבֹ֣תֵיכֶ֔ם', 'וּבְכֹרֹ֥ת']
 ‫ 12 :12 ['וּבְנֵיכֶם֙', 'וּבְנֹ֣תֵיכֶ֔ם', 'וְעַבְדֵיכֶ֖ם']
 ‫ 17 :12 ['וְתִֽירֹשְׁךָ֣', 'וְיִצְהָרֶ֔ךָ', 'וּבְכֹרֹ֥ת']
 ‫ 18 :12 ['וּבִנְךָ֤', 'וּבִתֶּ֙ךָ֙', 'וְעַבְדְּךָ֣']
Chapter  13
 ‫ 15 :13 ['וְדָרַשְׁתָּ֧', 'וְחָקַרְתָּ֧', 'וְשָׁאַלְתָּ֖']
Chapter  14
 ‫ 5  :14 ['וּצְבִ֖י', 'וְיַחְמ֑וּר', 'וְאַקּ֥וֹ']
 ‫ 5  :14 ['וְדִישֹׁ֖ן', 'וּתְא֥וֹ', 'וָזָֽמֶר׃']
 ‫ 26 :14 ['וּבַצֹּ֗אן', 'וּבַיַּ֙יִן֙', 'וּבַשֵּׁכָ֔ר']
 ‫ 29 :14 ['וְ֠הַגֵּר', 'וְהַיָּת֤וֹם', 'וְהָֽאַלְמָנָה֙']
Chapter  16
 ‫ 11 :16 ['וּבִנְךָ֣', 'וּבִתֶּךָ֮', 'וְעַבְדְּךָ֣']
 ‫ 11 :16 ['וְהַגֵּ֛ר', 'וְהַיָּת֥וֹם', 'וְהָאַלְמָנָ֖ה']
 ‫ 14 :16 ['וּבִנְךָ֤', 'וּבִתֶּ֙ךָ֙', 'וְעַבְדְּךָ֣']
 ‫ 14 :16 ['וַאֲמָתֶ֔ךָ', 'וְהַלֵּוִ֗י', 'וְהַגֵּ֛ר']
Chapter  20
 ‫ 14 :20 ['וְהַטַּ֨ף', 'וְהַבְּהֵמָ֜ה', 'וְכֹל֩']
Chapter  26
 ‫ 17 :26 ['וּמִצְוֺתָ֛יו', 'וּמִשְׁפָּטָ֖יו', 'וְלִשְׁמֹ֥עַ']
 ‫ 19 :26 ['וּלְשֵׁ֣ם', 'וּלְתִפְאָ֑רֶת', 'וְלִֽהְיֹתְךָ֧']
Chapter  27
 ‫ 12 :27 ['וְלֵוִ֣י', 'וִֽיהוּדָ֔ה', 'וְיִשָּׂשכָ֖ר']
Chapter  28
 ‫ 22 :28 ['וּבַקַּדַּ֜חַת', 'וּבַדַּלֶּ֗קֶת', 'וּבַֽחַרְחֻר֙']
 ‫ 22 :28 ['וּבַחֶ֔רֶב', 'וּבַשִּׁדָּפ֖וֹן', 'וּבַיֵּרָק֑וֹן']
 ‫ 48 :28 ['וּבְצָמָ֛א', 'וּבְעֵירֹ֖ם', 'וּבְחֹ֣סֶר']
Chapter  30
 ‫ 3  :30 ['וְרִחֲמֶ֑ךָ', 'וְשָׁ֗ב', 'וְקִבֶּצְךָ֙']
 ‫ 5  :30 ['וִֽירִשְׁתָּ֑הּ', 'וְהֵיטִֽבְךָ֥', 'וְהִרְבְּךָ֖']
 ‫ 16 :30 ['וְחֻקֹּתָ֖יו', 'וּמִשְׁפָּטָ֑יו', 'וְחָיִ֣יתָ']
Chapter  31
 ‫ 12 :31 ['וְהַנָּשִׁים֙', 'וְהַטַּ֔ף', 'וְגֵרְךָ֖']
 ‫ 20 :31 ['וּדְבַ֔שׁ', 'וְאָכַ֥ל', 'וְשָׂבַ֖ע']
 ‫ 20 :31 ['וַעֲבָד֔וּם', 'וְנִ֣אֲצ֔וּנִי', 'וְהֵפֵ֖ר']
------------------ 


Very nice. Note, by the way, that this will not exclude words where vav is part of the root (specifically Sh'mos 36:38, "וְאֶת-וָוֵיהֶם וְצִפָּה", which I think would be the only example in Tanach of a three word series with each word beginning with vav when one of the words starts with a vav that belongs to the root).

@Fred I don't know hebrew. Can we talk tomorrow via chat?

This is worth bonus points! If you share your code (and ping me) I want to give you some!

@CandidMoe I was just making a parenthetic observation, since the word "וו" ("vav", not to be confused with the individual letter vav "ו", although there is an etymological relationship) means "hooks" in Exod. 36:38, and the letter vav at the beginning of that word is part of the root. You answered the question well as asked, but I suspect that the OP was interested specifically in sequential words beginning with a vav as a prefix.

@הנערהזה Project uploaded at https://github.com/Candid-Moe/search/tree/main. I can't ping you in the chat; I don't know how write hebrew. You ping me.

1 - When the pattern is limited to <= 3 consecutive words, then your best bet now is https://www.mgketer.org/search by entering vav-asterisk, vav-asterisk, vav-asterisk into the search.  Their downloadable/installable desktop application is even more robust than their web-based search, but still limited to searching 3 words.
2 - As @shmosel hinted to in a comment, (my very own) Base Hasefer can search with an unlimited number of search terms and also do wildcard pattern based searches. Surrounding the search terms by double quotes will indicate that the words must be consecutive.
For example if you want to search Tanach for the roshei teivos of the name Moshe you would merely search on the pattern mem-asterisk, shin-asterisk, heh-asterisk like the following:

The one catch (something that I'm actually working on fixing for the next software update) involves the specific search case mentioned in your question when trying to search with repeated identical search terms such as the roshei teivos vav, vav, vav where the site currently won't find anything for it but the search on mgketer.org will.

Why don't repeated terms work? Is it a bug?

correct - it's been bothering me for a while. Hope to have a fix released within the next few months iy"H and will try to remember to post an update here when that happens.  For now, one can still find repeated occurrences of a search term in the Advanced Search by setting # of occurrences >= a specific amount. But it can't enforce finding consecutive matches one word apart.  Watch out for next week's parsha (Vayishlach) where we get the world-record of an entire 8-word pasuk (בראשית לב:טו) ending in mems. (וראה בעל הטורים שם)

Ty so much, though I dont speak Hebrew, so I wouldnt be able to navigate through the website

While the sample image above is in Hebrew, the site does have an English language user interface. To switch between the Hebrew and English UI there is a button on the upper right of the screen: when it says "English" and you click it, the UI will be toggled to English and when it says "עברית" and you click it, the UI will be toggled to Hebrew.   The source material from Tanach will always appear in Hebrew.

Secretorah.com has always worked best for me. They also have several other interesting options.

Very cool, thanks for sharing this (even though it's a secre)

The Bar Ilan Responsa program should let you do this (I have never tried to search that way) but it is not a free program -- you need to buy the program.
